# Submitting a Formik Form on Unmount

Tags: reactjs, formik

Is it possible to submit a Formik Form without having a submit button?
For example submitting the Form when the component unmounts so the user doesn't need to click a button to save.
Think of something like that:

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";

const Example = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      //trigger Submit or send Request with Form Values from here
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        //send Request
      }}
    >
      {() => (
        <Form>
          <Field name="firstName" />
          <Field name="lastName" />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a functional component that auto-submits. By having it render inside the  component, you have reference to the context of the form. You can use:

```
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';
 
 function AutoSubmitToken() {
   // Grab values and submitForm from context
   const { values, submitForm } = useFormikContext();

   React.useEffect(() => {
     return submitForm;
   }, [submitForm]);
   return null;
 };
```

You can use it under the  component as such

```
<Form>
   <Field name="token" type="tel" />
   <AutoSubmitToken />
</Form>
```

You can read all about it [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext)

Comment: Perfect it works thanks! I added a `dirty` check to only submit when the form is `dirty` (and you have to use `useRef` to get the latest value in the unmount function). Unfortunately there seems no way to give user a second chance when there is an error in the form.